# Creating shortcut on android

Tags: android

I need to create desktop shortcut for content managed by my app. I've found the way to do it using [ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION%5FCREATE%5FSHORTCUT) But I need the way to implement it without using "Create shortcut" menu. It would be great if user could select "create shourtcut" from item's context menu inside my activity and it will be automatically placed on desktop.

Thanks
Aleksander

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution. Just pass intent which you normally use to return when implementing activity with ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT to Activity.sendBroadcast().